# How can I Filter my recyclerview with TimePicker and numberpicker?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

i am learning android developement and I have to create an app to schedule meeting between co-workers, I have already did the biggest part of the job, but I am stucked now:

In my main activity I have a menu item, who got 2 item, the first is "filter by time" who displays a Time picker and the second one is "filter by place" who displays a number picker with 10 values converted to String value. When I choose a Time, I am supposed to filter my recyclerview and display only the meetings scheduled in the chosen time. And when I choose a place, my recylerview should display only the meetings scheduled in this place, so I have two filters. How can I do it?

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected( MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.filter_list:
            TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(this,
                    new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay,
                                              int minute) {


                        // what should I write here ?

                        }
                    }, mHour, mMinute, true);
            timePickerDialog.show();
            return true;

        case R.id.filter_place:

            NumberPickerDialog newFragment = new NumberPickerDialog();
            newFragment.setValueChangeListener(this::onValueChange);
            newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "time picker");

            return true;

    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


public void onValueChange(NumberPicker numberPicker, int oldVal, int newVal) {

    return; // what should I write here ?

}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. Firstly, to implement this, your meeting object(which u display in recyclerview) should have option to save(date and meeting).
2. Than there are a lot of ways how to implement filtering of recyclerview list. U can implement Filterable with your recyclerview adapter. So u will have method getFilter(), in which u will provide filtering

Here is example of how to do it:
https://www.androidhive.info/2017/11/android-recyclerview-with-search-filter-functionality/